# Use minimum of two threads in android?

Tags: android

When I was reading some posts here I noticed that android main thread is ui thread and that any long operation should be on another thread by its own

So I was wondering, if would it be a good design habit to always create two threads(at least) at for any Android app? One would be the UI thread that is used for updating UI and the other thread for any other thing

Or should I just stick with one thread and spawn a thread only when I need to (Long operation)

Thank u

Comment: It depends on your application. A game, a note application, a twitter client, etc. don't work equally, so you have to evaluate which is the better architecture for your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is heavily depend on your application. In simple words If user feel any lag in application, then your probably need to move your work in another thread. `AsyncTask` make it really easy to work with thread.

Comment: But is asyncTask another thread or is it still on the UI thread but sent as a message

Comment: yes doInBackgound run in different thread, but onPreExecute and onPostExecute run in UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, and I feel one could debate about this topic.

Yet my opinion and answer to your question would be:

No, you should only create an additional thread or AsyncTask when you are doing long operations eg. connecting to a server, downloading data from a server or doing some heavy lifting.

Smaller things would't be noticeable in terms of lag eg. simple math operations.

I hope this helps.